# When to require('webpack') in webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack

Just getting started with WebPack (Version 3.10.0) and I noticed that in some tutorials they include the following line:

`const webpack = require('webpack');`

While other tutorials omit it entirely. In reading the docs on plugins, it shows the following line in its `webpack.config.js` file:

`const webpack = require('webpack'); // to access built-in plugins`

Question: Is that (plugins) the ONLY reason why we would need to add this line to our config? Please advise.

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what you suggest. To get plugins, .etc. Don't require it if you don't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to import it if you don't need to reference it. You might import it if you want to use, for example, `webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin` or `webpack.DefinePlugin`.

Comment: OK, I see. So webpack's built-in plugins must be called like any other webpack plugin (e.g. clean-webpack-plugin) ...by using require. Got it.

Comment: Well some of them are exported as properties of the `webpack` object. So you don't always need to have a *further* `require` statement for each of those. You might have `...plugins: [new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({...}), ...` for example, after you've had `const webpack = require('webpack');` earlier. The config file isn't magic; it's just another JS file and follows the usual rules.

Comment: oooh nice! Still grokking the docs. But that is very helpful. Thanks!